# How would you debug a Cordova / Ionic app if another developer had forgotten to give you some files?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, transpiler

I'm taking over a Cordova / Ionic project. I'd like to run:

```
ionic build
```

or

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

but I get errors such as:

```
[17:13:17]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts, line: 16 
            Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'. Types of property 'lift' are 
            incompatible. Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: 
            Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'. Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'. Type 'T' 
            is not assignable to type 'R'. 

      L16:  export declare class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements ISubscription {
      L17:      observers: Observer<T>[];

[17:13:17]  typescript: src/components/push-notification/push-notification.ts, line: 61 
            Type '{ android: { forceShow: false; sound: true; }; ios: { alert: "true"; badge: false; sound: "true";...' 
            is not assignable to type 'PushOptions'. Types of property 'android' are incompatible. Type '{ forceShow: 
            false; sound: true; }' is not assignable to type 'AndroidPushOptions'. Property 'senderID' is missing in 
            type '{ forceShow: false; sound: true; }'.
```

I've done such things as:

```
pod setup
```

and:

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios

ionic cordova platform add ios
```

I think perhaps the previous developer did not commit all of their work.

I've spent a week reading articles on Stackoverflow and Github and followed the advice, but I can not get past these errors.

How would I debug this, especially assuming the previous developer may have forgotten to get me something essential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update your scripts

npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest

then run again

Comment: glad to be helpful :D